# Re-printing line in a loop if 'X' value isn't met in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, while-loop, text-based

I am trying to make my code re-print a line if the value isn't met.

I have tried using `while` but it wont revert back to the question if 'X' isn't greater than or equal to 1.

I am currently trying:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class rpg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double hp = 10;
        System.out.println("how much damage do you wish to do?");
        double attack = input.nextDouble();
        double damage = hp - attack;
        System.out.println(damage);
            System.out.println("health = " + Math.round(hp));
            while (hp <= 1) {
                System.out.println("Alive");
                break;
                }
            }
    }
```

but I can't get the question to re state when the hp is greater than 1 still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work read the comments

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double hp = 10;
    while(hp > 1) { //Moved The loop
        System.out.println("how much damage do you wish to do?");
        double attack = input.nextDouble();
        //double damage = hp - attack;//not needed
        hp = hp - attack;//Added this line
        //System.out.println(damage);//not needed
        System.out.println("health = " + Math.round(hp));
        if(hp == 0)
            System.out.println("Dead");
        else
            System.out.println("Alive");
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of asking a whole new question I thought i would ask you here. Are you able to help, if hp = 0 i want the statement to print out "dead" because the console adds the "Alive" even when hp = 0

Comment: @AlexO'Malley like that?